# ASP.Net IIS Worker Process (w3wp.exe *32) utilizing 100 CPU resources in production environment

Tags: asp.net, performance, cpu-usage, production-environment, w3wp

We recently deployed a new version of our web application to production with some significant changes to a relatively higher traffic page that loads various mortgage products.  Since the deployment, the this products page increased from 7 to 10 seconds to anywhere from 50 seconds to 2 minutes to load.  Also, the CPU utilization is now often maxed due to our IIS worker process (w3wp.exe 32) running on our dedicated production web server.  This unacceptably drastic loss in performance occurs on the Product page only, and not on any other pages.

I ran DebugDiag.exe on the server during a sustained duration of maxed out CPU Usage.  The culprit was again our Product page.  We have an average of 60 users during normal business hours and during peak times, the maxed out CPU significantly slows down the rest of the web application page loads.  We get the occasional http error code 501 which indicates server overloads & request failures.

I ran a Chrome Dev Tools > Network > Capture and see that (for example) one request to get just the products page itself (248k) takes 24 seconds, then several subsequent requests for a couple of 20kb Images and JavaScript Files takes even longer (24 to 50 seconds each) for a total page load time of 1.9 minutes (850k transferred, 93 total requests, DOMContentLoaded = 1.2 minutes.).

I don’t think a decrease in performance this substantial is due to inefficient asp.net or SQL code changes inherent in this new release (No worries on me trying to cover for myself;  it wasn’t my code anyway ;-)).  In pursuit of this theory, I noticed that after the bulk of the Product page content would load in the browser, Chrome would then issue another get request (http://ourcompany.com/ productpage.aspx?ImageControl_ctl00$ctl00$cphMainBodyFrame$ImageCompanyLogo=1) for the 12k company logo  which was housed in the master page asp.net ImageControl.  This request would take an average of an additional 40 seconds to complete.  So the logo wouldn’t show up until late in the game.

I ran Telerik’s JustTrace asp.net profiling tool my local DEV environment on the Product page which, despite the numerous calls to the database and data access layers, turned up nothing obvious in terms of performance bottlenecks.  Then I pasted the above logo url into the address while profiling in JustTrace and see that minimal processing is done to retrieve that logo.  Asp.net internally is calling only two stored procedures to the membership database to authenticate the user, along with some other minor system calls.  Despite the minimal asp.net and stored proc. calls, the request for the logo is taking far too long; and only for the Product page.

Could this be a session lock issue?  Also, I’ve read thousands of SO posts over the years and this is my first post.  Thanks SO community for all your support over the years.  It’s been an invaluable resource.

Win Server 2008 R2 (v6.1 Build 7601: SP1) - [VM with 8 CPU Cores > 32GB RAM]
IIS (7.5.7600.16385)
ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms 
MSSQL Server 12

Comment: When your server is fully utilizing the CPU to process the productpage.aspx page, obviously any other request to that same server is going to suffer also. So I would go back to square one and further analyze the most obvious suspect: the sole thing that changed between the site being relatively fast and it being unworkably slow: the products page.

Comment: Other Devs have been reworking the product page.  However, other pages in the application making their requests at the same time as the Products page perform swiftly unless the cpu is maxed for an extended duration. Also puzzling (as in the OP) just requesting the logo (Product Page Only) ex. (...productpage.aspx?ImageControl_ctl00$ctl00$cphMainBodyFrame$ImageCompanyLogo=1) itself by pasting above the link in Address bar takes an average of 45 seconds.  Only internal asp.net calls fire during that request including, I think, the asp.net session lock. Requests for 20k .js files also crawl

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer:**

We were using the Infragistics asp.net controls version 12.2.20122.2031 which works in legacy browsers. Upgrading to version 12.2.20122.2257 (also supports legacy browsers), not only *completely* solved the issue for our products page, but had a **drastic** effect on performance site wide.

**The long answer:**

During a sustained period of time that the web servers CPU’s were maxed, I was able to get a snapshot of the processes that were running.  I used a tool (DebugDiag) to analyze the snapshot and it generated a lengthy details report which featured the Infragistics GetLicense() function as requiring the most CPU resources.  It looked something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BRAS.png

I contacted Infragistics support about this and they directed us to the version 12.x.2257 controls which they said would address the performance problem.  We upgraded the Infragistics dll’s  in our DEV environment and our entire site went from an average of 6-15 seconds per page load to 2-3 seconds. Update panel async post backs were also substantially quicker to complete.

We were concerned with any risk due to issues that may arise from upgrading a control set we use consistently throughout the application.  Testing the upgrade revealed minor problems with IE DocMode = IE7 when typing the date manually in an Infragistics calendar control if our C# code dynamically created the control in the code behind.

**Why we use DocMode IE7**

Our web application was constructed during the glory days of IE7. The company grew rapidly and lots of code had to be written by many developers who have since come and gone.  There was never a decision to break away from the dependency on IE7 so the bulk of the application runs under IE DocMode = IE7.  This means that only legacy Infragistics asp.net controls (version <= 12.x) are compatible with our site.  Anything greater than version 12.x we experience display problems with the calendar control.

In conclusion; if this scenario sounds familiar to you, upgrade your controls and convince management to break away from IE7 dependencies at all costs.